# Multithreaded filesystem scan optimization

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization

What this program does is it scans the harddrive for all files. While the main thread is filling a queue with all the file paths, multiple worker threads start further inspection on the files. Right now I have this code:

**Scanner.cpp**

```
#include "Scanner.h"

Scanner::Scanner() : fsscan_done(false)
{
    num_threads = thread::hardware_concurrency() - 1;
}

void Scanner::ScanFile(fs::path path)
{
    ifstream file(path.c_str());
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        // further inspection
    }
}

void Scanner::ThreadScan()
{
    while (!fsscan_done || !files.empty()) {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);
        if (files.empty()) {
            lock.unlock();
            continue;
        }
        fs::path path = files.front();
        files.pop();
        lock.unlock();
        ScanFile(path);
    }
}

void Scanner::Scan()
{    
    vector<thread> thread_pool;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++)
        thread_pool.push_back(thread(&Scanner::ThreadScan, this));

    ScanDirectory("C:\\");
    fsscan_done = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++)
        thread_pool[i].join();
}

void Scanner::ScanDirectory(fs::path directory)
{
    for (const auto & entry : fs::directory_iterator(directory)) {
        if (fs::is_directory(entry.path()))
            ScanDirectory(entry.path());
        else {
            if (!fs::is_regular_file(entry.path())) continue;
            unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);
            files.push(entry.path());
        }
    }
}
```

**Scanner.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

class Scanner
{
private:
    unsigned num_threads;
    mutex mtx;
    queue<fs::path> files;
    bool fsscan_done;
    void ThreadScan();
    void ScanFile(fs::path file);
public:
    Scanner();
    void Scan();
    void ScanDirectory(fs::path directory);
};
```

I have the feeling this code can be optimized further, I especially don't fancy this part:

```
while (!fsscan_done || !files.empty()) {
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);
    if (files.empty()) {
        lock.unlock();
        continue;
    }
```

because I'm checking for *files* to be empty twice. I think there should be a better way to do this, at least I assume. I'm quite new to multithreading principles, so I have already looked around on SO and other sites, maybe condition variables can help me out here but I'm not so sure how to implement them in this case.

**EDIT:**

changed the directly locking and unlocking of the mutex to use a unique_lock, thanks [François Andrieux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55267878/c-multithreaded-filesystem-scan-optimization#comment97266920_55267878)

Comment: Beware that locking or unlocking mutex objects directly is looking for trouble. [`std::unique_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) is an RAII wrapper for managing locks safely.

Comment: If the drive is a spinning disk versus an SSD, you may find asking for multiple reads of different files concurrently is actually slower not faster.

Comment: @Evan thanks I considered this, for now I will assume the use of SSD

Comment: Yes, condition variables are what you want when you would otherwise be busy-waiting on a mutex.